# Issues with creating a new isolated scope in factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'd like to know what the consequences / issues of creating a new isolated scope in a factory are, by doing `$rootScope.$new()`

I'm trying to allow the user of my library to do something like `$cordovaPush.$on('notReceived')`, rather than using `$rootScope.$on('...')` (even though it may be pointless to do this). I've seen other comments about memory leaks and various other issues with creating a new scope, but I haven't found any proof or real convincing arguments as to why this should not be done.

Here's some code as a reference to what I'm doing:

```
.factory('$cordovaPush', ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($q, $window, $rootScope, $timeout) {

  var $cordovaPush = $rootScope.$new(true);

  $cordovaPush.onNotification = function (notification) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $cordovaPush.$broadcast('notificationReceived', notification);
    });
  };
  $cordovaPush.register = function (config) {
    ...
  };
  $cordovaPush.unregister = function (options) {
    ...
  };
  $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber = function (number) {
    ...
  };

  return $cordovaPush;
}]);
```

ALSO

If creating a new scope **is OK**, what is the best practice for destroying the scope? Is it necessary to destroy the scope if the app is closed and opened again?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think you should do this.

You are creating a scope object that isn't bound to a DOM element and it will never be destroyed unless manually done so by code, and the only benefit is to have a `$on` method. *If I'm reading your question correctly.*

```
$cordovaPush.$broadcast('notificationReceived', notification);
```

What child scopes will this broadcast too? Here's a clip from the manual

> **$broadcast**: Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

Since the scope isn't part of the DOM hierarchy. It's unlikely that any children will be created unless you create them manually.

> I'm trying to allow the user of my library to do something like $cordovaPush.$on('notReceived'), rather than using $rootScope.$on('...') (even though it may be pointless to do this).

You're trying to mix two different things.

1. A specific object the `$cordovaPush`
2. A non-specific event broadcasted to all children.

I'm wondering if a `factory` is the right approach for what you're trying to do. If I was working on an API like that I would use a directive and controller.

Here's an example of what I would do.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('cordovaPush',function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.register = function(config) {
                // ...
            };
            this.unregister = function(options) {
                // ...
            };
            this.setBadgeNumber = function(number) {
                // maybe this needs to broadcast? here's an example
                $scope.$broadcast('notificationReceived');
            };
        },
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr, ctrl) {
            // you can inject options from the DOM attributes to the controller
            ctrl.setBadgeNumber($attr['badgeNumber'] || 0);
        }
    }
});

// here is a directive that works with the above
app.directive('myStuff',function() {
    return {
       require: '^cordovaPush',
       link: function($scope, $el, $attr, cordovaPush) {
          $scope.$on('notReceived',function() {
              // ...
          });
          cordovaPush.register({});
          cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(2);
       }
});
```